# Using closed type families to write functions "if type A, then X, else type Y"

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function that has a specialized implementation for some types and a general implementation for all other types, with more magic than {-# SPECIALIZE #-} or rewrite rules can get me.  (Roughly, I want to switch from `IORef` to `Ptr` when possible.)

Closed type families look like they might provide a solution:

```
type family Specialized a where
   Specialized Foo = Bar
   Specialized a = Baz
```

...but it's unclear how, from here, to build a function `special :: Specialized a`, or something more or less equivalent.  Closed type families seem to work on the type level, but I can't figure out how to do the appropriate thing on the data level.

If I were willing to explicitly list all types I didn't want to specialize for, I could write a type class and make an `instance` for all the other types, but I want to write something that specializes a finite list of types and then does something else for *all* other types.

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: How about overlapping type classes with associated types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with overlapping classes. Here's an example for writing [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) which chooses a more efficient container type when the list is a list of ints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}

import           Data.IntSet (IntSet)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type family Container a where
  Container Int = IntSet
  Container a = Set a

class Monoid (Container a) => Uniqable a where
  insert :: a -> Container a -> Container a
  member :: a -> Container a -> Bool

instance Uniqable Int where
  insert = IntSet.insert
  member = IntSet.member

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Ord a, Container a ~ Set a) => Uniqable a where
  insert = Set.insert
  member = Set.member

uniq :: Uniqable a => [a] -> [a]
uniq xs = foldr f (const []) xs mempty
  where
    f x a s
      | member x s = a s
      | otherwise = x : a (insert x s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without overlapping instances using an auxiliary class. The following is based directly on oisdk's answer. The fundamental idea is that you can use the result of a closed type family application to select an instance.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
-- So we don't have to futz with proxies
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import           Data.IntSet (IntSet)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type family Container a where
  Container Int = IntSet
  Container a = Set a

class Monoid (Container a) => Uniqable a where
  insert :: a -> Container a -> Container a
  member :: a -> Container a -> Bool

class Uniqable' c a where
  insert' :: a -> c -> c
  member' :: a -> c -> Bool

instance (Uniqable' c a, Monoid c, c ~ Container a) => Uniqable a where
  insert = insert' @c
  member = member' @c

instance Uniqable' IntSet Int where
  insert' = IntSet.insert
  member' = IntSet.member

instance Ord a => Uniqable' (Set a) a where
  insert' = Set.insert
  member' = Set.member

uniq :: Uniqable a => [a] -> [a]
uniq xs = foldr f (const []) xs mempty
  where
    f x a s
      | member x s = a s
      | otherwise = x : a (insert x s)
```